# Allow some custom elements Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, custom-element, transclusion

Say I would like to permit specific custom elements (for example):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'transcludor',
  template: `
    <div class='transcludor'>
      <span class='slot-one'>
        <ng-content select='slot-one'></ng-content>
      </span>
      <span class='slot-two'>
        <ng-content select='slot-two'></ng-content>
      </span>
    </div>
  `})
export class Transcludor{
//stuff goes here
end
```

Which I then use with:

```
<transcludor>
  <slot-one>
    stuff
  </slot-one>
  <slot-two>
    stuff
  </slot-two>
</transcludor>
```

This fails with:

```
polyfills.js:3 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
'slot-one' is not a known element:
```

Now, adding `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to my `@NgModule` schema *does* make the problem go away, but it also allows any and all custom elements.

Is it possible to define a specific set of permitted custom elements (that aren't themselves components) to empower (for example) transclusion.

e.g. I would like:
`<slot-one></slot-one>` and `<slot-two></slot-two>` to be permissible, but for `<slot-three></slot-three>` to throw the above exception.

Bonus points if this can be scoped to specific contexts (e.g. within the `transcludor` component.)

Comment: Have you tried to create a separate module for this component and add the `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` only to this module?

Comment: Not sure if this will work but maybe using ContentChild so your transcludor component can look for specific components and them project them using ngTemplateOutlet.